# How do I fix the "401 Unauthorized" error with Laravel 8 Sanctum and VueJS 3?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-sanctum

So I have this `Laravel 8` project with `VueJS 3` in the frontend, and I'm running it on my localhost
And I'm using `Sanctum` for my authentication.
The Login and Sign Up process works fine, but when I go to a dashboard and I try to add something to my database it gives me the `401 Unauthorized` error.

**Laravel:**

**EDIT:** **UserController**

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ];

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $success = true;
            $user = User::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first();
            $token = $user->createToken("authToken")->plainTextToken;
        } else {
            $success = false;
        }

        $response = [
            'success' => $success,
            'access_token' => $token,
        ];
        return response()->json($response);
    }
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

**api.php**

```
// Auth
Route::post('login', [UserController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('register', [UserController::class, 'register']);
Route::post('logout', [UserController::class, 'logout'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');

// Niveau
Route::group(['prefix' => 'niveaux', 'middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [NiveauScolaireController::class, 'index']);
    Route::post('add', [NiveauScolaireController::class, 'add']);
    Route::get('edit/{id}', [NiveauScolaireController::class, 'edit']);
    Route::post('update/{id}', [NiveauScolaireController::class, 'update']);
    Route::delete('delete/{id}', [NiveauScolaireController::class, 'delete']);
});
```

**cors.php**

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
'exposed_headers' => [],
'max_age' => 0,
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

**sanctum.php**

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
    'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS',
    'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
    env('APP_URL') ? ',' . parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
))),
```

**session.php**

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

So that's what I set up for the Laravel side.

**VueJS**

**app.js**

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./Router/index";
import axios from "axios";
const app = createApp(App);
app.config.globalProperties.$axios = axios;
app.use(router);
app.mount("#app");
```

**bootsrap.js**

```
window.axios = require("axios");
window.axios.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
windoow.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

**Login component**

```
this.$axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie").then((res) => {
    this.$axios
        .post("api/login", {
              email: this.email,
              password: this.password,
        })
        .then((res) => {
            if (res.data.success) {
                this.$router.push({ name: "Dashboard" });
            } else {
                console.log("Error: " + res.data.message);
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("error :>> ", error);
        });
    });
```

Here my request for `sanctum/csrf-cookie` is going well and I’ll receive Cookies, the login works fine, it gets the user from the database, and then it redirects me to the dashboard.

**Problem**
Now here when I try to send a request to `(api/niveaux/add)` the request is sent, but I get a `401 Unauthorized` error with a `{"message":"Unauthenticated."}` response.

**Dashboard component**

```
this.$axios
    .post("api/niveaux/add", {
        nom: this.niveau,
    })
    .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.success) {
            alert(res.data.message);
        } else {
            alert(res.data.message);
        }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("error :>> ", error);
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the question. I have the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to send you `access_token` in every request that has `middleware('auth:sanctum')` in laravel.
you can find `access_token` inside the cookie you get after logging in. (might have different name like `token`)

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${access_token}`
```

or

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `${access_token}`
```

gotta do the trick

Comment: I've tried it but its not working, Ive edited my question and added the UserController, and in my `boostarp.js` file i made the changes you told me todo, but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

I think you are accessing through localhost port 8000, but in your stateful param under sanctum config, there is no `localhost:8000`. The config uses $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] so it actually looks for the exact content while accessing it.

**sanctum.php**

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
    'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS',
    'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
    'localhost:8000',
    env('APP_URL') ? ',' . parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
))),
```

Comment: I tried it, still the same "401" error, do you have any other idea that might be causing this problem

Answer (score 0):

noticed a typo here:

```
window.axios = require("axios");
window.axios.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest";
windoow.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

the last "windoow" was spelt wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When I experienced this, I traced and compared changes to an existing working project

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
    'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS',
    'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
    env('APP_URL') ? ',' . parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
))),
```

in `config/sanctum.php` had been changed, I just replaced it with the old code

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env(
    'SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS',
    'localhost,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1,' . parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST)
)),
```